# Java heap and stack memory allocation

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

```
class Person{
          private String name;
          public Person(){
          }

          public Person(String name){
              this.name=name;
          }

          public static void main(String[] arg)
          {
                Person per= new Person("Andy");
          }
    }
```

`per` is a local variable, where will it be stored, on the heap or the stack?

Comment: You might consider changing your accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the heap.  Any time you use `new` to create an object, it is allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 30):

Objects are always stored in the *heap*. However, the *reference* to `per` will be stored in the *local variable array*, which is stored in the *frame* created for `main(String[])`, which is stored in the *stack*.

For more information, see: [The Structure of the Java Virtual Machine](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html).

**Edit:** I've learnt that JVMs are actually able to allocate objects on the *stack* by performing [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis). Better yet, a technique called *scalar replacement* can be applied, where the object allocation is omitted, and the object's fields are treated as local variables. It is possible for the variables to be allocated on machine registers.

Escape analysis by stack allocation has been implemented by HotSpot VMs since Java 6u14. It has been enabled by default since Java 6u23. For an object to be allocated on the stack, it must not escape the executing thread, the method body or be passed as an argument to another method.

Comment: “*the reference to per*” is misleading. `per` is the local variable containing a reference to the object created via `new Person("Andy")`. The value of the local variable will be stored in the stack frame, which is the reference to the object. You could also say, there is memory reserved in the stack frame for the local variable `per`. As much as needed for a reference to an object. But I think, that’s what you actually wanted to say…

Comment: @Holger: That is what I wanted to say, but I suppose it wasn't clear enough. Thank you for clarifying.